# How to pass multi select data using GET in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I'm writing a code to search a list in angular, there I need to pass filtering options (form fields) to the API via GET call. this is working but, when there are multi select options (when passing an array within the GET call), there is a problem of doing it

Just think of country list in angular material select with multi option enabled

This is the format of parameters (if there is an error which I should follow in the GET call)

```
&country[]=LK,&country[]=UK&country[]=US
```

code is working for normal form fields without any issue, following is the code

```
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let params = new HttpParams();
            let headers = new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            });

            params = data;

            this._httpClient.get<any>(requestUrl, { headers, params })
                .toPromise()
                .then(
                    res => {
```

How I get the selected options as an array withing GET parameters

Comment: Ideally this should be done in POST. Is there any particular reason why you want to use GET?

Comment: Yes its because of the way API work. But I believe you are correct. Anyway thanks

Comment: Can you show what the API expect through a postman screenshot

Comment: I wish if I can. but I'm working under restricted env. Im not suppose to discuss the exact API calls or data due to NDA terms. Im extremely sorry.

However this API is a GET call, say

------------------------------------------------
{{api_url}}/item/?shape[]=RD&shape[]=OT&color[]=F&price[lte]=260&price[gte]=12&price_type=P&package=S
------------------------------------------------------

Comment: this returns the data with pagination links. so pagination links contains the page ids as well as above parameters .

---------------------------------------------
 "links": {
        "first": "URL/item/?shape%5B0%5D=RD&shape%5B1%5D=OT&color%5B0%5D=F&price%5Blte%5D=260&price%5Bgte%5D=12&price_type=P&package=S&page=1",
        "last": "URL/item?shape%5B0%5D=RD&shape%5B1%5D=OT&color%5B0%5D=F&price%5Blte%5D=260&price%5Bgte%5D=12&price_type=P&package=S&page=1",
        "prev": null,
        "next": null
    },
----------------------------------------------

Comment: so the API expects multi select arrays in get calls to perform the search and it will include again within the pagination links (means it works in get calls).

So this was the base for my question, I need to get values from multi select dropdown and generate the query string as folows (

---------------------------------------------------
&country[]=LK,&country[]=UK&country[]=US
--------------------------------------------