# Angular pass data to a shared module

Tags: angular

I'm writing a code to get member list from API and display it in member card list (Module A). member card is a shared module (Module B). importing module B to module A and display as a list is works without issue (with just hard coded html). 
However I need to pass each member data from module A to Module B within the loop in order to show the data in member card. Please help me to get an idea on how to pass the data to module A to Module B

[image]

I have followed  this reference https://medium.com/frontend-fun/angular-4-shared-modules-18ac50f24852 in order to create the member card list using shared member card module.

In my Module A I have imported the member card module

```
 import { MemberCardModule} from 'app/shared/member-card/member-card.module';
```

```
  declarations: [MemberListComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    MemberCardModule,
......
```

In component.html (Module A) following is the code for member card loop

```
<app-member-card *ngFor="let member of members"></app-member-card>
```

** I have members array within the component.ts (Module A)

During the loop, I need to pass each member data to the member-card template in Module B.

Please help

Comment: Why you need module B for this? why not on the same module?

Comment: this member card will be used in many places within the app. this is why I need to use it as a shared module

Comment: You're confusing modules and components. A parent component can pass data to a child component, using inputs. Whether the components are part of the same module or not doesn't change how you do that. And you don't pass data between modules, but between components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example of using @Input() for *MemberCardComponent* class.

In member-card.module.ts

```
import { MemberCardComponent } from "./member-card.component";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MemberCardComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        MemberCardComponent
    ]
})
export class MemberCardModule {}
```

In member-card.component.ts

```
export class MemberCardComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() member: any;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

In member-card.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="member">
    {{ member.name }}
</div>
```

In member-list.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        MemberCardModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MemberListComponent
    ]
})
export class MemberListModule { }
```

In member-list.component.html

```
<app-member-card [member]="member" *ngFor="let member of members"></app-member-card>
```

Comment: This is another question I m having can you kindly check this and give me your thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934149/how-to-pass-multi-select-data-using-get-in-angular-7

Answer (score 14):

To pass data to a shared module, do the following steps:

**Module A:**

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  ModuleB.forRoot({
    memberData: memberData
  })
]
```

**Module B**

```
export class ModuleB{ 
  static forRoot(memberData): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: ModuleBModule,
      providers: [ModuleBService,{provide: 'memberData', useValue: memberData}]
    };
  }
}
```

**Module B Service**

```
export class ModuleBService{

  constructor(@Inject('memberData') private memberData:any) {
    console.log(memberData)
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Guess I need to get the data to the component through the service with this approach.

Comment: Yes, this is the way to pass data to a module according to your question. But as provided in the other answers, for your particular requirement passing at component level will do

Comment: This is another question I m having can you kindly check this and give me your thoughts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57934149/how-to-pass-multi-select-data-using-get-in-angular-7

Comment: Yes sure. I agree, I understood that there was an issue with the way I asked the question when I looked at your answer. Surely there will be  cases that this approach is much better than @Neda's answer - Many thanks Adrita

Comment: Yes, no issue. if somebody google search this question, will find this answer helpful as it is required in many cases. A good example is passing environment variable to a Custom Library Module

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add an `Input` in the `app-member-card` component that accepts a member.

In your MemberCardComponent:

```
export class MemberCardComponent {
  @Input() member: Member;

  constructor() {} ...
```

In the parent's template:

```
<app-member-card [member]="member" *ngFor="let member of members"></app-member-card>
```

Comment: Thanks I played with the code with this and always got the "member" as a string within the shared component.  @Neda peyrone 's solution worked. it should insert [member]="member". anyway thanks,

Comment: You're right, my bad. Forgot to add the braces. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can import MemberCardModule into AppModule directly.
Or import into ShareModule and import ShareModule into AppModule.
It is important to import Modules into AppModule.
And then you can you MemberCardModule.

Regarding the display MemberCard, you should use `*ngFor` in its parent div.

Look at this:

```
<div *ngFor="let member of members">
  <app-member-card [member]="member" />
</div>
```